# d programming, parse or convert string to double

Tags: string, double, d, typeconverter, dmd

as easy as it is in other languages, i can't seem to find an option in the d programming language where i can convert a string (ex: "234.32") into a double/float/real.

using atof from the std.c.stdio library only works when i use a constant string. (ex: `atof("234.32")` works but `atof(tokens[i]);` where tokens is an dynamic array with strings doesn't work).

*how to convert or parse a string into a real/double/float in the d-programming language?*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Easy.

```
import std.conv;
import std.stdio;    

void main() {
    float x = to!float("234.32");
    double y = to!double("234.32");

    writefln("And the float is: %f\nHey, we also got a double: %f", x, y);
}
```

`std.conv` is the swiss army knife of conversion in D. It's really impressive!

Comment: yep, 'to' is freakin' awesome! :)

Answer (score 9):

To convert from most any type to most any other type, use [`std.conv.to`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html). e.g.

```
auto d = to!double("234.32");
```

or

```
auto str = to!string(234.32);
```

On the other hand, if you're looking to parse several whitespace-separated values from a string (removing the values from the string as you go), then use [`std.conv.parse`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_conv.html). e.g.

```
auto str = "123 456.7 false";

auto i = parse!int(str);
str = str.stripLeft();
auto d = parse!double(str);
str = str.stripLeft();
auto b = parse!bool(str);

assert(i == 123);
assert(d == 456.7);
assert(b == false);
```