# Convert string to array of int's

Tags: d

I have got string like:
`string mystr = "1,2,3,4,5";`
I need convert it to array of `int`'s like: `int [] myints`. How can I do it?

Comment: conversion see  [d programming, parse or convert string to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605641/d-programming-parse-or-convert-string-to-double) for inspiration

Comment: no, arrays can be converted differently which makes the answer here more unique

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you format your string like `"[1,2,3]"` (`'[' ~ mystr ~ ']'`) you can just import std.conv and call `mystr2.to!(int[])`. (whitespaces don't matter here, as long as it starts with `[` and ends with `]`)

Otherwise if you have an array of int strings (`["1", "2", "3"]`), like you would get from a `split` call you can use `myarr.to!(int[])` too and it will convert each string to an int. (make sure you don't have whitespaces here, otherwise you would call `.map!(a => a.strip.to!int).array`)

Basically `to` can do everything on arrays which it can do on primitives too.